# Can not detect received SMS android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am trying to get received SMS in my phone through programatically.

Below permissions are added,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Added the receiver

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Declare SMS Broadcast receiver -->
        <receiver android:name=".SMSBReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

In the `BroadcastReceiver` class

```
public class SMSBReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note : I have checked that in the Application management enabled the Permission for `SMS`

Let me know any thing missed ?

Comment: Is the `<receiver>` element in the right spot in the manifest; i.e., between the `<application>` tags? Are you sure the `name` attribute is pointing to the right class? Have you launched an `Activity` in your app at least once after installation to bring it out of the _stopped_ state? Does your device have any additional settings/permissions beyond the standard ones that restrict third-party apps from receiving SMS by default? How exactly are you determining that this isn't working?

Comment: @MikeM.: yes, I have added the < receiver > inside the application tag. I have edited that part. please have a look.  I haven't get any call in 'onReceive' , hence I it is not working.

Comment: @VineeshTP are you asking for runtime permission?

Comment: You're missing the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission. Just saw it.

Comment: @MikeM.: Thank you...!! . I had missed the *&# (Permission) :)

Answer (score 2):

try this my friend

**1. crate a broadcast receiver**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static SmsListener mListener;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");

    for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

        String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        //You must check here if the sender is your provider and not another one with same text.

        String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();

        //Pass on the text to our listener.
        mListener.messageReceived(messageBody);
    }

}

public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
}
```

**2. create one smslistener interface like this**

```
public interface SmsListener {
public void messageReceived(String messageText);
}
```

**3.in your acitvity java file add this code**

```
 requestSmsPermission();//method for sms recevied permission


 SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener() {
        @Override
        public void messageReceived(String messageText) {
            Log.d("Text", messageText);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message: " + messageText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });

 private void requestSmsPermission() {
    String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
    int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] permission_list = new String[1];
        permission_list[0] = permission;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
    }
}
```

**4.add permission to manifiest file**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

5. add broadcast receviver to manifiest file

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

Comment: The issue was I missed to add the permission